# Error in paragraph breaking due to \raisebox

Tags: math-mode, raise

I want to make a horizontal line to separate stuff in my document, like this:

[image: separator line]

But then, I notice that bellow the vertical spacing between a paragraph and an equation is not what it has to be:

[image: separation with equation]

The courious thing is that if I comment the separation line it works just fine.

[image: no separation line]

Here my command:

```latex
\newcommand*{\labline}[1]{%
\setbox\z@\hbox{#1}\relax%
\begin{center}%
\hrulefill\raisebox{-0.45\ht\z@}{\:#1\:}\hrulefill\null%
\end{center}%
}%
```

And the code that generates the paragraphs and equation

```latex
\kant[9]
\labline{Separator}
\kant[10]
\[ \text{Total derivative: }\frac{\mathrm{d}^3f}{\mathrm{d}x^3} \]
```

**MWE**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%% The command %%
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\labline}[1]{%
\setbox\z@\hbox{#1}\relax%
\begin{center}%
\hrulefill\raisebox{-0.45\ht\z@}{\:#1\:}\hrulefill\null%
\end{center}%
}%
\makeatother

\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\section{With the separator}
\kant[1]
\labline{Separator}
\kant[1]
\[ \text{Total derivative: }\frac{\mathrm{d}^3f}{\mathrm{d}x^3} \]

\newpage

\section{Without the separator}
\kant[1]
\kant[1]
\[ \text{Total derivative: }\frac{\mathrm{d}^3f}{\mathrm{d}x^3} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am suspecting the issue is with a display equation following `\kant`, rather than with your `\labline` definition. (If I type the text of `\kant[1]` in directly, no problem arises)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just an artifact of the `\kant` macro which ends in a paragraph break. You should never have a pargraph break before a displayed equation. Here you get `\abovedisplayshortskip` which has a natural size of 0pt, but is only intended for cases where the final row of the paragraph does not overlap the equation.

See `\kant[1]x`   for text that does not end with a paragraph break and triggers the intended use of `\abovedisplayshortskip`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%% The command %%
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\labline}[1]{%
\setbox\z@\hbox{#1}\relax%
\begin{center}%
\hrulefill\raisebox{-0.45\ht\z@}{\:#1\:}\hrulefill\null%
\end{center}%
}%
\makeatother

\title{}
\author{}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\section{With the separator}
\kant[1]
\labline{Separator}
\kant[1]x
\[ \text{Total derivative: }\frac{\mathrm{d}^3f}{\mathrm{d}x^3} \]

\newpage
\showoutput

\section{Without the separator}
\kant[1]
\kant[1]x
\[ \text{Total derivative: }\frac{\mathrm{d}^3f}{\mathrm{d}x^3} \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since the title of my question does not reflect the real problem, should I change the title?

Comment: @AmadoC yes you could